# Saving Files Locally

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to create a page where there are links to online pdf's.
When you click these links, it will save the file locally, and add a name / path to local storage.
I then iterate over the local storage keys, to display links to each saved file.

I'm having issues with saving files locally. I tried using chrome filesystem api:

```
function saveFile() {
        chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({
            type: "saveFile",
            suggestedName: "file.txt"
        },
        function (savedFile) {
            localStorage[s] = saveFile.fullPath;

        });
    }
```

but I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chooseEntry' of undefined.

Essentially, I need to save a file to the system, and get that path. It is preferable if there is no prompt to select name/location.

Comment: So if it can't read property chooseEntry, then either fileSystem or chrome is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is a Chrome extension then I think it is likely that the fileSystem API has not been enabled. For a chrome app you need to enable it via the [manifest.json file](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage#filesystem-manifest) for that application, you may also be able to ask for [user permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions).

If it is for a web application then you can request the file system using [window.webkitRequestFileSystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) although this will only be possible in Chrome (and maybe still Opera).

For cross browser file storage and download support you could use something like [Dexie](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js) for browser [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) storage and the [FileSaver](https://github.com/ChenWenBrian/FileSaver.js) and [Blob](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js) libraries although you will not have the same storage capacity and flexibility than with the native chrome APIs. Here is an example for FileSaver & Blob:

```
var blob = new Blob([data.text], {
    type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"
});
saveAs(blob, data.label + ".csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Google Chrome Application?

If so, you must have the following entry in your manifest file:

```
   "permissions" : [
                       {
                          "fileSystem" : ["write", "directory"]
                        }
                   ]
```

(Be careful with the spelling. I encountered the error because I wrote `permission` instead of `permissions`)